# perl while loop not working

Tags: perl

Below is my file which I am seperating by delimeneter and further sending through email
list : Device1|City|Street|roadname|region|state|area|country|countrycode

```
________________________________________________
Device1|City|Street|roadname|region|state|area|country|countrycode
Device2|City|Street|roadname|region|state|area|country|countrycode
Device3|No data found
Device4|No data found
_________________________________________________
my $filename = '/tmp/list.txt';
open my $ifh, '<', $filename
  or die "Cannot open '$file' for reading: $!";
local $/ = '';
my $filename = <$ifh>;

my @arr = split(/\|/, $filename , -1);
$Device = $arr[0];
$Region = $arr[2];
$State = $arr[3];
$area = $arr[10];
$country = $arr[19];

$logger->debug("$logid >> file information Device Name: $Device");
$logger->debug("$logid >> file information Region: $Region");
$logger->debug("$logid >> file information State: $State");
$logger->debug("$logid >> file information Area: $area");
$logger->debug("$logid >> file information Country: $country");

close( $ifh );
```

I am able to get below info but my requirement is whenever in the line it shows "No data found" assign it to variable for eg.. "pattern" which i will further send via email.

```
$smtp->datasend("$Device1|$region|$state|$area|$country\n");
$smtp->datasend("$pattern\n");
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is really unclear. There's no while loop in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I have tried doing somthing like below but it's not working ...$Device = $arr[0];
$condition = "$Device|No data found";
while (<>) {
   if ($line =~ /$condition/) {
      print $condition;
     $pattern = $condition
   }
}

Comment: Please go back and modify your question to include the entire code, not just selected parts of it.  Also, **what does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $INPUT, '<', '/tmp/list.txt' or die $!;
while (<$INPUT>) {
    chomp;
    my ($device, $data) = split(/\|/, $_, 2);
    if ($data eq 'No data found') {
        # Do whatever you need to do when there is no data
    } else {
        my @values = split(/\|/, $data);
        my ($region, $state, $area) = @values[3,4,5];
        # Further processing as needed
    }
}
close $INPUT;
```

A few notes:

- always `use strict` and `use warnings` - it will catch many problems for you.  Like the fact that you declare `my $filename` twice.
- The third argument to `split` is optional and only meaningful if it is positive.
- You're setting `$/ = ''` presumably to slurp the whole file at once, but you want to process it line-by-line.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rick!!! I have copied your code but seems it's not matching the condition and going in else loop open my $INPUT, '<', '/tmp/list.txt' or die $!; while (<$INPUT>) { my ($device, $data) = split(/\|/, $_, 2); if ($data eq 'No data found') {$logger->debug("$logid >> No data found :  $data"); } else {

Comment: Ah - that's probably because of the line endings.  I've updated the code to remove the trailing `/n` with `chomp`.